# Delete Statement Doesn't Use Index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-performance

I've got a table with the following schema...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Object1](
[id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
[Column1] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Column2] [int] NOT NULL,
[Column4] [char](4) NOT NULL,
[Column5] [money] NOT NULL,
[Column6] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[Column7] [char](6) NOT NULL,
[Column3] [bit] NOT NULL,
[Column8] [bigint] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [pk_Object1] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
([id] ASC) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF
, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)) 
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Object1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Object1_Column1]  DEFAULT (getutcdate()) FOR [Column1]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Object1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Object1_Column3]  DEFAULT ((0))     FOR [Column3]
GO
```

Each night, a delete query runs against this table...

```
delete from Object1 
where ( Column1 < DATEADD(dd, -40, GETUTCDATE()) )
OR ( Column3 = ? and Column1 < DATEADD(dd, -3, GETUTCDATE()))
```

The table has

1. Index2 (id) - clustered, unique located on PRIMARY
2. Index3 (id) - nonclustered located on PRIMARY
3. Index1 (id) - nonclustered, unique, primary key located on
   PRIMARY
4. Index4 (Column7) - nonclustered located on PRIMARY
5. Index5 (Column2, Column7, Column4, Column5) - nonclustered
   located on PRIMARY

The query produces the following plan...

[Execution Plan for Delete Statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTVK7.png)

The statement causes blocking in a highly concurrent table. The blocking ripples into system errors.

If I recreate "Object1_IX" to cover the "Object1" field, this still happens. The table has 6,568,449-rows and trims about 200,000 a night.

Comment: you have a function in the WHERE clause that involves the columns.  that means the optimizer has no way to know what the function will evaluate to, thus resorts to scans.   Try eliminating the functions themselves, or try using CROSS APPLY.

Comment: 23% of your query is spent deleting index 2. Have you considered dropping this index before and recreating after (online)?

Comment: First really having so many UDF in where clause will perform very poorly.So first you hv to correct your query itself.Also those 5 points about index are not clear to me.Those column belong to which table.[dbo].[Object1] do have any CI.is it so ?

Comment: The efficiency of the statement itself aside, deleting 200.000 rows at once can cause problems with I/O contention even if you had perfect indexes and could guarantee no blocking on row locks whatsoever. You may want to consider deleting rows in batches of however many your server can efficiently handle. Also, it looks like your `DELETE` is deleting two entirely different categories of outdated records -- splitting it up in two statements allows you to optimize them individually.

Comment: @Nick: No, Index2 is the table's clustered index.

Comment: @Greg: Replacing the functions with variables gives no change.